# Themify icons not showing in Angular CLI 8.2.2

Tags: angular, npm, webpack

I have installed Themify via npm npm install --save @icon/themify-icons from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@icon/themify-icons.
I use this approach to insert an image into site

```
<img height="32" width="32" src="@icon/themify-icons/icons/arrow-up.svg"/>
```

And is showed a broken image.
When I use remote CDN like this

```
<img height="32" width="32" src="https://unpkg.com/@icon/themify-icons/icons/arrow-up.svg" />
```

it is showing without a problem. But I don't want to use remote CDNs.

Also when I use this approach to insert stylesheets in head tag locally or with remote CDN in index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@icon/themify-icons/themify-icons.css">
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@icon/themify-icons/themify-icons.css">
```

and to insert tag in app.component.html:

```
<i class="ti ti-arrow-up"></i>
```

is not functioning. Squares are showed instead of icons.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

import below CDN in index.html file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@icon/themify-icons/themify-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@icon/themify-icons/themify-icons.css">
```

Add this link in your template(html) file

```
 <i class="ti ti-arrow-up"></i>
```

Comment: As I already wrote above unfortunately is not functioning. Squares are shown.

Comment: I caught it in code inspector :) , my app.component.css file was overwriting the style for i tag.